# How to resize the hbox to fit the contents in it when resizing the browser in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have a `hbox` in which I have some form elements. When I reduce the browser size, the contents on the right side of the `hbox` goes out of the window, they are simply invisible. I want them to come closer and readjust when the browser size is changed.

The width of all the elements is `100%`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Show your code if possible.. this will help to try out your task.

Comment: Are there any parent containers above the HBox or it's placed in the application? If the HBox is placed in other containers, make sure that they have appropriate width (in this case, 100%) as well. Some code will be helpful too, as the previous commenter said.

Answer (score 1):

On the resize event of the main application you can use following code,
the trick is to catch the resize event after the app has initialized and get the app width and set that to anything u want.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" resize="refreshApplicationState()" width="100%" initialize="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public static var isAppInitialize:Boolean = false;
            public function init():void{
                isAppInitialize = true;
            }
            public function refreshApplicationState():void{
                if(!isAppInitialize){
                    return;
                }
                testHbox.width = this.width - 10;
            } 
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:HBox id="testHbox" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:TextArea width="100%" />
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: i have used this approach successfully in a complex application. Hope this will help.

Comment: It is a nice suggestion. Thanks majid.